# How to get real time date from server in android?

Tags: android, android-date, android-dateutils

I have one android application which will show random Quotes everyday from application's
database, but when i change date in my android phone, i will get the future quotes. To stop this i need current date and time from server side ?

**Is there any URL or web service which gives real time data ?**

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this service : http://timezonedb.com/api. But its not recomended to use an external service for that.

You should probably use your own server.